# A "general" DuckDuckGo news page similar to the Google News one?

Tags: duckduckgo

At DuckDuckGo.com, when you have searched the web for a term you get an option to follow up by searching news, i.e. news webpages in particular. But is there a way to browse directly to (and therefore also to bookmark) a DuckDuckGo page that simply links to "top" news items without using a specific search term, as there is with Google News (news.google.com)?

The best I have got so far is to search news webpages on "a" OR "the":

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=a+the&iar=news&ia=news

Answer (score 1):

No, DuckDuckGo does not have a news page like Google does. Your shortcut is probably the best way to quickly generate one.

You could email DDG to suggest adding a news page: open@duckduckgo.com.

Answer (score 1):

DDG is a search engine, not a news aggregator service.

> DDG does not have something like this.

Souce: stormtm @ [Does DuckDuckGo have a news aggregator like Google News?](https://www.reddit.com/r/duckduckgo/comments/lupgj0/does_duckduckgo_have_a_news_aggregator_like/). /r/duckduckgo (Reddit)